# Left joining two views is slow?

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT DISTINCT
viewA.TRID, 
viewA.hits,
viewA.department,
viewA.admin,
viewA.publisher,
viewA.employee,
viewA.logincount,
viewA.registrationdate,
viewA.firstlogin,
viewA.lastlogin,
viewA.`month`,
viewA.`year`,
viewA.businesscategory,
viewA.mail,
viewA.givenname,
viewA.sn,
viewA.departmentnumber,
viewA.sa_title,
viewA.title,
viewA.supemail,
viewA.regionname
FROM
viewA
LEFT JOIN viewB ON viewA.TRID = viewB.TRID
WHERE viewB.TRID IS NULL
```

I have two views with a about 10K and 5K records in them.  They each come in very quickly - fraction of a second.  When I try to get all of the records that are not in ViewB from ViewA, it works but it is very slow.  All of the underlying TRID fields are same char set and all set to varchar (10) and indexed and tables are all Innodb.  Right now the query is taking 16 seconds.  Anything that I can do?

Comment: Did you tried removing left join and just use join?

Comment: @AshReva - That is extremely fast, but it returns nothing.

Comment: How many records, on average, does this return? What's the query behind the second view look like?

Comment: @MarcusAdams - 10k-5k = 5k - it varies a bit on ViewB which fluctuates from 5-6K.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, with `JOIN`, MySQL has to do a lookup for each joined record. Lookups are fast when using keys, but in your case, there aren't really any keys because the joined table is a view.

To try to get MySQL from running the query behind the second view once per record in the first view, we can use a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM viewA
WHERE TRID NOT IN (SELECT TRID FROM viewB);
```

This should allow MySQL to get all the TRID values for viewB in the subquery (in a temp table) then do a search over them for each record in viewA.

From [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-subqueries.html):

> MySQL executes uncorrelated subqueries only once. Use EXPLAIN to make
>   sure that a given subquery really is uncorrelated.

Comment: Surely you didn't want the `NOT` keyword? OP is filtering to get records with `TRID IS NULL`, so you might as well replace `TRID NOT IN (SELECT TRID FROM viewB)` with `TRID IS NULL` (Robert's answer).

Comment: @DavidKnipe, I re-read the original query, and I still think `NOT IN` is correct.

Comment: I don't see it myself... unless it's some SQL weirdness where `NULL IN (...)` evaluates to false because it's `NULL` (I seem to recall `NULL != NULL` in SQL). Well it's a moot point anyway if Robert's solution is better, as I believe it is.

Comment: @MarcusAdams - .14 seconds!!  Big thank you.  It is almost too fast.  Now I feel very compelled to update my other views that use a similar join (might be over 100).

Comment: @DavidKnipe - already implemented it on 3 tables and works exactly like the LEFT OUTER but literally 100 times faster.

Comment: @DavidKnipe, blankip is trying to get all rows from the first view where the IDs are not in the second view. I recommend reading the original query until you grok. :)

Comment: Just so everyone understands the use basis.  ViewA is simply all of our users for our site.  ViewB is our "important users".  What makes an important user... god only knows but I get an email a week with a different case.  There are currently about 40 rules for important users that use probably 10 different fields.  So when reporting I have many reports for the important users, but people also want to see how it compares to the other users.  I don't want to reverse engineer for to get the non-important users so I have to do this query.

Comment: Just to be clear . . . the `in` version works *faster* than the `left outer join`.  I thought MySQL could identify a `left outer join` with a comparison to `NULL` and optimize its performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - is there a reason it didn't?  Table type/setup or something?

Comment: @blankip . . . No.  I suspect that the optimizations just don't work the same way on views.  The right place to ask *that* question is dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Right, got it now, I didn't realise `LEFT JOIN` produces records with `NULL` values where there's no match. I never claimed I actually know SQL :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to optimize queries with views in MySQL.  My first suggestion is to get rid of `distinct` unless you absolutely know that it is needed.

Then you might compare the performance with this query:

```
select viewA.*
from viewA
where not exists (select 1 from viewB where viewB.TRID = viewA.TRID);
```

It is hard to say whether one will be better than the other, but it is worth trying to see if this is better.

Comment: Takes about a half second longer.  Am I setting up my DB wrong.  These subsets are very informal (there is no field that signifies them but they are created using a bunch of rules and cases) and mainly used for reporting.

Comment: @blankip . . . Indexes might help.  But what is happening is that `viewB` runs quickly.  It then has to do a slow join to combine with `viewA`.  You might ask another question, that includes the contents of the views along with these two SQL statements, and any indexes on the table.  Then ask how that might be optimized.  I think it is unfair to rewrite this question because it already has multiple answers.